# com.android.volley.AuthFailureError in Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to use Google Speech api to translate text from any language to English. There is no error in api connection but

> volley

is giving me error.
Thanks for help.
My Activity code:

```
 private void Translate(String s) {

    //trim out translate
    final String stringToTranslate = s.substring(9);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_CONNECTION,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
              Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                                  params.put(TO_TRANSLATE, stringToTranslate);
              return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

My PHP Server file, it is in the server and link to this file is provided by URL_CONNECTION Constant

```
<?php

use Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$fb = $_POST['toTranslate'];

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$translate = new TranslateClient([
    'key' => 'My TranslateApi key'
]);

        $result = $translate->translate($fb, [
                  'target' => 'en'
        ]);

$conversion =  $result['text'];

echo $conversion;
}

?>
```

When i run this activity it toast com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
I googled but i didn't get the relevant answers.

Comment: Anyone please i am stuck in this.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. It turned out I was overriding the wrong method to pass parameters. I should send them by the Header, so I changed my code to

```
"@override public Map<String, String> getHeaders()"
```

instead of

```
"@override protected Map<String, String> getParams()"
```

Maybe it's also your case, you need pass by the header of the message.